# Mutation in GraphQL using apollo and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apollo-client, aws-appsync

```
const query = require('graphql-tag');
  const x = query(`
  mutation Hello {
  putPost(
    category: "College",
      institution: "Some College",
      address: "DisneyLand",
      country: "India",
      state: "Some State",
      city: "Some City"
  ){
    category
  }
}`);

  const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: url,
    region: region,
    auth: {
      type: type,
      apiKey:apiKey,
    }
  });
  console.log(x);

  client.hydrated().then(function (client) {
    return client.mutate({mutation : x})
  }).then(function logData(data) {
    console.log("This is the data returned " + data);
  }).catch(console.error);
}
```

I am trying to mutate my database using AWS services and their Apollo SDK, i am unable to mutate my data and an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'queryManager' of undefined" occurs, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

After digging a bit i found that it is a problem with the version of Aws-appsync module. I installed '1.0.22' and everything worked fine. I hope it helps someone.